# SEVERE: null sql syntax error ;

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

```
public static void Student(int a,int rNo,String nm,String sn,int id,int age,Date bd,String gen,String nati,String rg,String fee,String insti,String crs,String sd,String email,int phn,String add,byte[]img) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String sql[]={"INSERT INTO studentreg (regNo,name,sname,idNo,age,birthD,gen,national,relegion,fee,institute,pro,sDay,eMail,phnNo,address,img) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
               ,"UPDATE studentreg SET ( regNo , name , sname , idNo , age , birthD , gen , national , relegion , fee , institute , pro , sDay , eMail , phnNo, address , img ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE regNo = '+rNo+'" };

    if(con==null)
        connect();

    psm=con.prepareStatement(sql[a]);
    psm.setInt(1,rNo);
    psm.setString(2, nm);
    psm.setString(3, sn);
    psm.setInt(4, id);
    psm.setInt(5, age);
    psm.setDate(6, bd);
    psm.setString(7, gen);
    psm.setString(8, nati);
    psm.setString(9, rg);
    psm.setString(10, fee);
    psm.setString(11, insti);
    psm.setString(12, crs);
    psm.setString(13, sd);
    psm.setString(14, email);
    psm.setInt(15, phn);
    psm.setString(16, add);
    psm.setBytes(17, img);
    psm.executeUpdate();
```

----------Error is this

```
- Dec 28, 2014 1:25:28 PM GUI.studentInfo btnUpdateActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(regNo,name,sname,idNo,age,birthD,gen,national,relegion,fee,institute,pro,sDay,e' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at Model.DbConnect.Student(DbConnect.java:59)
    at Model.studentEdit.studentGet(studentEdit.java:97)
    at GUI.studentInfo.btnUpdateActionPerformed(studentInfo.java:1006)
    at GUI.studentInfo.access$1400(studentInfo.java:24)
    at GUI.studentInfo$15.actionPerformed(studentInfo.java:831)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement uses a syntax that does not exist, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clearly have an error in your second SQL query :

```
UPDATE studentreg SET ( regNo , name , sname , idNo , age , birthD , gen , national , relegion , fee , institute , pro , sDay , eMail , phnNo, address , img ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE regNo = '+rNo+
```

An update must be defined in this form :

```
UPDATE studentreg SET regNo = ?, name = ?,  ...
```

And so on ...

Please read the [UPDATE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) .

Answer (score 0):

You are using update similar to insert like:

```
UPDATE studentreg SET ( regNo , name , sname , idNo , age , birthD , gen , national , relegion , fee , institute , pro , sDay , eMail , phnNo, address , img ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE regNo = '+rNo+'"
```

You could do something like:

```
UPDATE Table SET regNo = i.regNo, name = i.Name, ...
FROM (SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM  other_table WHERE regNo = 'rNo') i
```

Comment: You have identified the cause, but not given a solution.

Comment: Your latest edit added a solution that uses a syntax that doesn't exist.

Comment: hmmm what is i ? its unclear for me could u explain it for me

Comment: @DanRox So treat i as a temporary table which will contain all the columns from your table with regNo as 'rNo' and then you are using those columns values to update your table.